# How to interpret various colors in matplotlib plot of a mp3/wav file

Tags: python, audio, matplotlib, wave

I'm a python newbie and audio analysis newbie. If this is not the right place for this question, please point me to right place.

I have an mp3 audio file which has just silence. 
Converted to .wav using sox 
`sox input.mp3 output.wav`

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(fs,x)=read('/home/vivek/Documents/VivekProjects/Silence/silence.wav')
##plt.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 5000 # for preventing overflow error. 
fs
x.size/float(fs)
plt.plot(x)
```

Which generates this image:

[image]

I also used solution to this question: [How to plot a wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625085/how-to-plot-a-wav-file)

```
    from scipy.io.wavfile import read
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # read audio samples
    from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read audio samples
input_data = read("/home/vivek/Documents/VivekProjects/Silence/silence.wav")
audio = input_data[1]
# plot the first 1024 samples
plt.plot(audio)
# label the axes
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.xlabel("Time")
# set the title  
plt.title("Sample Wav")
# display the plot
plt.show()
```

Which generated this image:

[image]

Question:
I want to know how to interpret the different color bars(blue green,yellow) in the chart.   If you listen to the file it is only silence, and I expected to see just a flat line if anything.

My mp3 file can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzrlbg0llwoy5yi/silence.mp3?dl=0).
The sox converted wav file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtg8yj983w3d3gq/silence.wav?dl=0).

Even though the file is silent, even dropbox is generating a waveform. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Just because you can't hear anything doesn't mean it is _complete_ silence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, always check the shape of your data before plotting.

```
x.shape
## (3479040, 2)
```

So the 2 here means you have two channel in your .wav file, matplotlib by default plot them in different colors. You will need to slice the matrix by row in this situation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ind = int(fs * 0.5) ## plot first 500ms
### plot as time series
plt.plot(x[:ind,:])
plt.figure()

#### Visualise distribution
plt.hist(x[:ind,0],bins = 10)
plt.gca().set_yscale('log')

##### 
print x.min(),x.max()
#### -3 3
```

As can be seen from the graph, the signal is of very low absolute value (-3,3). Depending on the encoding of .wav file (integer or float), it will be translated to amplitude (but probably a very low amplitude, that's why it's silent).

I my self is not familiar with the precise encoding. But this page might help: http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html

> 1. For all formats other than PCM, the Format chunk must have an extended portion. The extension can be of zero length, but the size
>      field (with value 0) must be present.
> 2. For float data, full scale is 1. The bits/sample would normally be 32 or 64.
> 3. For the log-PCM formats (µ-law and A-law), the Rev. 3 documentation indicates that the bits/sample field (wBitsPerSample)
>      should be set to 8 bits.
> 4. The non-PCM formats must have a fact chunk.

[image: time_series]
[image: histogram]

PS: if you want to start some more advanced audio analysis, do check this [workshop](http://musicinformationretrieval.com/index.html) which I found super practical, especially the Energy part and FFT part.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is meant by plotting at `high frequency`. I want to know why there are multi color peaks in the plot. Also if you take a look at the files on dropbox, they are also generating a waveform. any hints as to why that could be happening.

Comment: Nice use of the histogram to show the distrubution, +1. You should probably delete the ---old answer --- part though

Comment: Advice adopted @DavidG

Answer (score 1):

I had a suspicion that your `silence.mp3` file had audio which was very low (below human hearing) since I couldn't hear it even when I played at maximum speaker sound.

So, I came across plotting audio frequency from `mp3` from [here](http://myinspirationinformation.com/uncategorized/audio-signals-in-python/)

first we convert `mp3` audio to `wav`. As parent file is stero, converted `wav` file is stereo as well. In order to demonstrate that there are audio frequencies , we just need single channel.
Once we have single channel `wav` audio, we then simply plot `frequency` against `time` index with a color-bar of `dB` power level.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
from pydub import AudioSegment
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import fft as fft

#read mp3 file
mp3 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("silence.mp3")
#convert to wav
mp3.export("silence.wav", format="wav")
#read wav file
rate,audData=scipy.io.wavfile.read("silence.wav")


#if stereo grab both channels
channel1=audData[:,0] #left
#channel2=audData[:,1] #right channel, we dont need here


#create a time variable in seconds
time = np.arange(0, float(audData.shape[0]), 1) / rate

#Plot spectrogram of frequency vs time
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,6))
plt.subplot(211)
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(channel1, Fs=rate, NFFT=1024, cmap=plt.get_cmap('autumn_r'))
cbar=plt.colorbar(im)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
cbar.set_label('Intensity dB')
plt.show()
```

As you can see in the image , the `silence.mp3` does contain audio frequencies possible with power level of -30 to -45 dB.
[image]

Comment: so what is being saved in `audData` ?

Comment: audio samples are saved in `audData` as numpy array. You can check as  `type(audData)` -> <type 'numpy.ndarray' ,  audData ->
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       ..., 
       [-1,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0]], dtype=int16)

Comment: Sir, I meant is it amplitude or decibel or power .. what is"feature" being stored in audData?

Comment: None of the above. Wav file stores data in  linear pulse-code modulation (LPCM) format. Their  data-type as indicated by numpy array is 'int16' which denotes '16-bit PCM'. Chck out https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html and also WIKI on wav https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV